# Identifying non grid tables in a word docx in python

Tags: python-3.x

[This is the image of the docx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrecE.jpg)I have some tables in the word file sheet from which i would like extract data from

I have tried extracting the text from the file and using regex . I tried to split the the text into tables

```
import docx
document = docx.Document('2.docx')
docText = b''.join([paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs])
print (docText)
```

I don't really understand how to go about it using regex or is there any other method to go about it,I do want to specify the area and extarct the contents

Comment: So basically you have your data in a MS Word template form and you are looking for a script to extract data from there?

Comment: Yes,but as can see only one table i.e the History table gets identified and the other without the grid wont be identified so i wanted to call all the other tables in a df,Iam finding it very difficult for identifying those paticular tables

Comment: Unless this is a school project, the above can be done more conveniently using `macros` .

Comment: No this a not a school project,iam a broker who is new to python,and i wanted to apply some logic on the extracted data,can you tell me how to go about it,thanks